# OSB WLST importError: no module named security in 12c

Tags: weblogic12c, osb, wlst, soa-suite

in SOA suite 12c, I am running a sample OSB WLST script which has from com.bea.wli.sb.security.management.configuration import ALSBConfigurationMBean
but getting an import error as no module named security, have added all the jars from %OSB_HOME%/lib/modules/*.jar and %OSB_HOME%/lib/*.jar, but still getting the same import error, any idea how to resolve this, also could you please help on this query, is it possible to select/attach the OWSM policy to a proxy service using the wlst script, if so please advice how it can be achieved?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as classpath goes, the classpath I use to call WSLT is:

```
${weblogic.home}/server/lib/weblogic.jar:${osb.home}/modules/*:${osb.home}/lib/alsb.jar:${osb.home}/lib/sb-kernel-wls.jar:${osb.home}/lib/sb-kernel-impl.jar:${osb.home}/lib/sb-kernel-api.jar${osb.home}/lib/modules/*:${osb.home}/lib/transports/*
```

(replace with windows-style `;` path separators if required)

> is it possible to select/attach the OWSM policy to a proxy service using the wlst script, if so please advice how it can be achieved?

Personally, I'd extend [Configurator](https://github.com/tomecode/OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator/wiki/OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator) so I could add it to the sb-jar, preferably before it goes into a Maven repository. I believe I've mentioned something similar in a [question you asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163658/how-to-select-owsm-policy-for-the-osb-proxy-service-using-the-wlst-script).

Comment: Thanks a lot Trent for the reply. I am now trying the wlst scripting in my local server, I have added/referenced all the jars in the OSB folder, now added the ${osb.home}/lib/transports/* jars too in the wlst.cmd file in the ${MW_Home}/oracle_common]\common\bin\wlst.cmd file, still see the same error.  Sure, thanks a ton for the reply to the second query.

Comment: Did you do `${osb.home}/modules` as well?

Comment: Yes Trent, I have added all the jars under OSB for initial script running.